# Undeclared identifier for NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

In the interface (.h) of the viewController:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* myMutableArray;
```

calculate method is as:

```
- (void) calculate {

    DataObject* pObj = [DataObject objStart:(dataStart) objEnd:(dataEnd) objDay:(day)];

    [myMutableArray addObject:pObj];

}
```

I receive this error message:

Use of undeclared identifier 'myMutableArray': did you mean '_myMutableArray' ?

Comment: Did you `@synthesize` the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using XCode4 :)

Here you are not required to @synthesize. Compiler creates all ivars itself as _ivarName.
i.e.,

```
@synthesize myMutableArray=_myMutableArray;
```

If you want to override it then you can as

```
@synthesize myMutableArray;
```

or, in this way

```
@synthesize myMutableArray=myMutableArray;
```

Comment: ehm, i'm solved adding self.MyMutableArray and obvious i'm using Xcode 4.x. all that make sense?

Comment: Thats good. As I saw your points, I felt you are new, and if I can help you get something or just a revision. Also self.ivar= and _var= both plays vital roles.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the property synthesized manually (`@synthesize myMutableArray;`) 
 the compiler will create an iVar with an underscore prefix (which is the same as `@synthesize myMutableArray = _myMutableArray`);

To access it use

```
[_myMutableArray addObject:pObj];
```

or

```
[self.myMutableArray addObject:pObj];
```

If you have it synthesized manually like this

```
@synthesize myMutableArray = nameOfMyBackingIVar
```

you can access your `NSMutableArray` this way:

```
[nameOfMyBackingIVar addObject:pObj];
```

Comment: no i don't have the property synthesized manually but i add self.myMutableArray and it seems to work properly .. thanks ! I don't know that i have to call also array with self. i thought only objects needs to be called with self.

Comment: you can access all properties via self.myProperty or [self myProperty] / [self setMyProperty:...]